# How can I enumerate a list of coset representatives?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to enumerate a list of (left) coset representatives for a quotient group (say, $A/B$) with the following properties:

(a) No two members of the list represent the same coset.

(b) Every coset is represented by some member of the list.

For context, my goal is to construct a set of these representatives so that I ensure that the set's cardinality equals the order of $A/B$.

**My attempt:** Use the bijection $f\colon A/B \to A$ such that $f(xB) = x$.

Does this work?

**Edit**: It was pointed out that my function is (clearly) not well-defined. So, my question remains, but I now realize that my attempt won't work.

Comment: $f$ in your attempt is not a well defined function. You can have $x\neq y$ and $xB=yB$.

Comment: @drhab Right, that's true. I had a feeling the function didn't work. Is there any bijection I could use?

Comment: In the general case not that I know off. There is a choice function of course, but that only guarantees the existence of such a bijection. A look at [transversals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_(combinatorics)) might give you some insight.

Comment: 1) Take a set on which $A$ operates and the stabilizer of some point $X$ is $B$ ($A/B$ will work, but might not be the nicest one).
2) Use the orbit algorithm or however you call it to compute orbit, stabilizer and orbit representatives (e.g. for every $m$ in the orbit compute a $a \in A$ such that $ax = m$).
3) By the orbit stabilizer theorem, these $a$ will be your representatives.

If you don't know how to compute orbits then your problem might get a little harder to solve.

Comment: @Bemte Thank you, but unfortunately I don't know how to compute orbits yet. A left transversal seems to be what I'm looking for. My new question, then, is how do I form a left transversal for $B$ in $A$. Is there a general algorithm for obtaining one?

Comment: What you need is a right inverse to the canonical projection $\pi\colon A\to A/B$.  Its existence depends, for infinite $A/B$, on the axiom of choice.

Comment: Is $A$ finite? $B$? $A/B$?

Comment: @egreg Right, thank you. I was just thinking that ultimately it may be enough (for my purposes, at least) to invoke the AoC. (And $A/B$ need not be finite.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is finding a right inverse to the canonical map $\pi\colon A\to A/B$, which exists by the axiom of choice.

I don't think you can avoid AC when $A/B$ is infinite. If you have more information on specific $A$ and $B$ an explicit right inverse might be given also in the infinite case, but I guess the existence of a transversal set (the image of a right inverse to the projection) for every group and subgroup thereof is equivalent to AC.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, and I agree. Thanks!